# Trying to understand how to structure my data for a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm learning about ggplot and wanted to build a example plot based on randomly generated dummy data. But I'm getting a ggplot error (which I'm purposefully leaving till the end, since I actually want to step back and ensure I've understood how my ideal data should look).

I've built a dataset with the following blocks:

```
# dimensions
channels <- c("Facebook", "Youtube", "SEM", "Organic", "Email", "Direct")
last_month <- Sys.Date() %m+% months(-1) %>% floor_date("month")
mts <- seq(from = last_month %m+% months(-23), to = last_month, by = "1 month") %>% format("%b-%Y")
dimvars <- expand.grid(Month = mts, Channel = channels)

# metrics
rws <- nrow(dimvars)
set.seed(123)
Sessions <- ceiling(rnorm(rws, mean = 3000, sd = 300))
Transactions <- ceiling(rnorm(rws, mean = 200, sd = 40))
Revenue <- ceiling(rnorm(rws, mean = 10000, sd = 100))

# make df
dataset <- cbind(dimvars, Sessions, Transactions, Revenue)
```

Here's what it looks like:

```
head(dataset)
     Month  Channel Sessions Transactions Revenue
1 May-2015 Facebook     2832          136    9979
2 Jun-2015 Facebook     2931          179   10017
3 Jul-2015 Facebook     3468          142   10117
4 Aug-2015 Facebook     3022          228   10106
5 Sep-2015 Facebook     3039          285   10115
6 Oct-2015 Facebook     3515          149    9943

> str(dataset)
'data.frame':   144 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Month       : Factor w/ 24 levels "May-2015","Jun-2015",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Channel     : Factor w/ 6 levels "Facebook","Youtube",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Sessions    : num  2832 2931 3468 3022 3039 ...
 $ Transactions: num  136 179 142 228 285 149 232 231 214 160 ...
 $ Revenue     : num  9979 10017 10117 10106 10115 ...
```

Now that I have a dataset I want a plot of Sessions overtime. So I tried this:

```
##  Timeline Plot
timeline <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x = Month, y = Sessions, color = Channel)) +
  geom_line()
```

Before running the timeline code I had an expectation in my head of how it would look. I was expecting to have a chart with the 24 months along the x axis, sessions along the Y and then a different coloured line for each channel (so 6 lines)

When I type timeline in the console a chart is generated but with 144 non distinct months, not 24 as I had hoped. I sort of see what ggplot is doing, it's trending sessions but not grouping months and channel to get distinct values for month/channel and instead plotting the full ungrouped data.

1. Did I structure my data in a logical way to achieve my goal? Obviously I need to change it, but in thinking through which dimensions and metrics I want to play around with, does my structure make sense or should I have done it differently from the outset?
2. What should I do to get the plot the way I want? 24 points on the x-axis with 6 different coloured line charts for each channels sessions.

I considered using tidyr package `spread()` function to spread sessions by channel. I think this would work but have not tried it. I'm hesitant to do that because I'm going to eventually want to also trend Transactions and Revenue metrics, which would mean adding a lot of columns to my dataframe. This seems "untidy". So philosophically, what would my ideal dataframe look like?

Comment: Try adding `group = Channel` to your aes: `ggplot(dataset, aes(x = Month, y = Sessions, color = Channel, group = Channel)) + geom_line()`. This happens because Channel is a factor, which means ggplot2 has to be told to connect lines across different values

Comment: Hey it worked! Thanks. Would you say my data structure is fine and I should focus on using ggplot to do the grouping over amending the underlying dataframe? What's best practice here?

Comment: Your data looks fine to me, it's in proper "long" format which is what ggplot works best with. Something like `spread()` would make your data "wide", which is not what you want.

Comment: Your structure looks good here! Treating each month as an observation lets you calculate/plot revenue/transaction or revenue/session easily. The exception would be if you wanted to plot sessions, transactions and revenue on (for example) three separate facets, in which cause you could `tidyr::gather()` those three columns.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on this, very helpful on solidifying my understanding of how ggplot works with data